# Which control would be a better fit to this problem?

Tags: android, android-controls

Requirement:
I have a `GridView` of thumbnails; the user can click on a thumbnail to view the larger, full sized image. This "full sized" image is to be fetched from a remote server. When the user is viewing a particular image he should be able to cycle through all of them by swiping his fingers on the screen(like leafing through pages of a book).

Questions:
1. What component should be used to display the larger version of the bitmap? I thought of using a `ViewFlipper` as it only seems logical to me. But I haven't used it before and am not sure of how I will create a new View every time, dynamically and pass it to the Flipper. Any tutorial that exemplifies this would be great.
2. Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may take some work to integrate into your own project (I know because I've done it) but look at the solution from the Android source's Camera app in [ViewImage.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/ViewImage.java;h=3ee3029eb656e2719396b81ed1f5cf81a55f6b5d;hb=HEAD); they use a scrollable/zoomable touch view that has auto-hiding controls overlaid for zoom and next/previous buttons. There's a lot of extra stuff in there too that needs decoupling before you can use it in your own app, but that's the core idea from a UI standpoint.

It'll also be familiar to your users; if there's no compelling UI reason to surprise your users with an image detail view that does something new, use the same one they're used to from the built-in Camera/Gallery app.

For what it's worth, the 2.1 camera app seems to do away with the next/prev buttons and replaces them with swipe left/right gestures.